# What is a good way to automate distribution fitting in python?

Tags: python, computational-statistics, parameterization, finite-mixture-model

I have to do some **distribution fitting** of 120 data subsets.

They take the form of financial transactions amounts and timestamps.

Timestamp, BTC, EUR, USD

I know from some other analysis that each subset will have different distributions, but the format of the data is the same for all data sets.

My goal is to get a best fit and the parameters for each data set from the exercise. Because I know I want to build a **mixture model** from these distributions, so ideally this gives me a 'bank' of distributions and parameter ranges to draw from, when producing a mixture model in the future.

I'm happy to check results by hand, but I'm hoping there's some **automation** tricks I can use to distribution fit all of them at once, as well as some collective wisdom about how to do distribution fitting of many sample sets simultaneously.

What **python libraries** should I consider for the distribution fitting, and which should I avoid?

When comparing a grouping of samples that share fitted distributions, how shall I try to conceive of the range of parameters as part of a 'generative function' for producing sub-populations? For example, say I get distribution fits for Exponential, with four different parameterisations. Do I take the min and max values as boundaries, or could I turn the four of them into some sort of probability distribution for the subpopulation generating functions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.